# how to get the last login of the users on Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows, windows-7, user-profile

I need to get the last login time of each users on windows 7.
The purpose is to clean up old user profiles from the machine based on the last login time. The NTuser.DAT is not useful since any application update on for all users also updating NTUSER.DAT file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are local accounts, you can use [NetUserGetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the [USER_INFO_11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

> usri11_last_logon
>
> The date and time when the last logon occurred. This value is stored as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00, January 1, 1970, GMT.